# Ubuntu 20.04 sudden boot error

Tags: boot, bug-reporting

Without any update or change in file system Ubuntu boot error occured.

I tried to boot from the recovery mode, first time it was successful so I updated the system but the problem still persists and I cannot boot into the system even from recovery mode.

Also giving some error about initramfs decoding failed.

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend booting from a live installation medium (Ubuntu ISO) and then running `e2fsck /dev/sda7` to check the filesystem for corruptions.

Comment: Thanks but I think keyboard was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour of search, I realized that it was caused because a laptop key was automatically pressed (don't know how the keypress triggered this serious error).

After fixing the keyboard problem (cleaning and reinserting the internal keyboard) the boot problem was automatically solved.